# My print method wont work using UTF8String

Tags: objective-c

I have two classes, Song class, and Playlist class.

This is the Song.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Song : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *artist, *title, *album, *time;

-(void) setSong:(NSString *)theSongName andArtist:(NSString *)theArtist andAlbum:(NSString *)theAlbum andPlayingTime:(NSString *)theTime;

@end
```

Song.m

```
@implementation Song

@synthesize title, album, artist, time;

-(void) setSong:(NSString *)theSongName andArtist:(NSString *)theArtist andAlbum:(NSString *)theAlbum andPlayingTime:(NSString *)theTime{

    self.title = theSongName;
    self.artist = theArtist;
    self.album = theAlbum;
    self.time = theTime;
}

@end
```

Playlist.h

```
@interface PlayList : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *playListName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *songsCollection;

-(void) addSongToPlayList:(Song *) someSong;
-(void) removeSongFromPlayList:(Song *) theSong;
-(void) print;

@end
```

Playlist.m:

```
@implementation PlayList

@synthesize songsCollection, playListName;

-(void) addSongToPlayList:(Song *) someSong{

    [songsCollection addObject:someSong];
}


-(void) removeSongFromPlayList:(Song *)theSong{

    [songsCollection removeObjectIdenticalTo:theSong];
}

-(void) print{

        NSLog(@"================= Playlist Name: %@ =============", playListName);
    for (Song *nextSong in songsCollection){
        NSLog(@"Artist         Song         Album         Time");
        NSLog(@"------         ----         -----         ----");
        NSLog(@"%s             %s           %s            %s  ", [nextSong.artist UTF8String], [nextSong.title UTF8String], [nextSong.album UTF8String], [nextSong.time UTF8String]);
        NSLog(@"=================================================");
    }
}

@end
```

The `print` method is the one giving me problems, it just prints this line:

`NSLog(@"================= Playlist Name: %@ =============", playListName);`

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Song.h"
#import "PlayList.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Song *song1 = [[Song alloc] init];
        [song1 setSong:@"Flying away" andArtist:@"Madona" andAlbum:@"Love collection" andPlayingTime:@"3:52"];

        PlayList *playList1 = [[PlayList alloc] init];
        [playList1 setPlayListName:@"Cool Soongs to listen"];


        [playList1 addSongToPlayList:song1];
        [playList1 print];



    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check if it is entering the loop?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya what do you mean Anoop?

Comment: entering in ` for (Song *nextSong in songsCollection){` loop

Comment: No, it's not entering the loop i think, how do i fix this? @AnoopVaidya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not `alloc`+`init`ed `songsCollection`.

Create an `init` method in PlayList.m and put below there

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        songsCollection=[NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not populating your `songsCollection` array properly (i.e. it's empty), due to the definition of its property:

```
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *songsCollection;
```

You need to change it to (ARC):

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *songsCollection;
```

or (MRR):

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *songsCollection;
```

Also change all references from `songsCollection` to `self.songsCollection` within the `PlayList` class.

Comment: why not use weak instead of strong in ARC?

Comment: @LithuT.V Because you want to maintain the reference to the array as long as the `PlayList` object exists.

Comment: @Nir See my update; you need to use `self.songsCollection` within the `PlayList` class.

Comment: @Nir Anoop has the right answer, but don't forget to put back the `copy` attribute if you think that is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSLog(@"================= Playlist Name: %@ =============", self.playListName);
```

`songsCollection` array may not have a valid memory.Use strong.Instantiate it in your method

```
-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    self.songsCollection =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
    return self;
}
```